# I keep getting a C2198 Error in my program for C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void wordGenerator(unsigned int number[]); // prototype
// function to form words based on phone number
void wordGenerator(unsigned int number[])
{
    unsigned int loop; // loop counter
    unsigned int loop1; // loop counter for first digit of phone number
    unsigned int loop2; // loop counter for second digit of phone number
    unsigned int loop3; // loop counter for third digit of phone number
    unsigned int loop4; // loop counter for fourth digit of phone number
    unsigned int loop5; // loop counter for fifth digit of phone number
    unsigned int loop6; // loop counter for sixth digit of phone number
    unsigned int loop7; // loop counter for seventh digit of phone number
    FILE* foutPtr; // output file pointer
    char* phoneLetters[10] = { "", "", "ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL",
    "MNO", "PRS", "TUV", "WXY" }; // letters corresponding to each number
    if ((foutPtr = fopen_s("phone.out", "w")) == NULL) // open output file
        puts("Output file was not opened.");
    else
    { // print all possible combinations
        for (loop1 = 0; loop1 <= 2; ++loop1)
            for (loop2 = 0; loop2 <= 2; ++loop2)
                for (loop3 = 0; loop3 <= 2; ++loop3)
                    for (loop4 = 0; loop4 <= 2; ++loop4)
                        for (loop5 = 0; loop5 <= 2; ++loop5)
                            for (loop6 = 0; loop6 <= 2; ++loop6)
                                for (loop7 = 0; loop7 <= 2; ++loop7)
                                    fprintf(foutPtr, "%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",
                                        phoneLetters[number[0]][loop1],
                                        phoneLetters[number[1]][loop2],
                                        phoneLetters[number[2]][loop3],
                                        phoneLetters[number[3]][loop4],
                                        phoneLetters[number[4]][loop5],
                                        phoneLetters[number[5]][loop6],
                                        phoneLetters[number[6]][loop7]);
        // output phone number
        fputs("\nPhone number is ", foutPtr);
        // loop through digits
        for (loop = 0; loop <= 6; ++loop)
        {
            // insert hyphen
            if (loop == 3)
                fprintf(foutPtr, "-");
            fprintf(foutPtr, "%d", number[loop]);
        } // end for
    } // end else
    fclose(foutPtr); // close file pointer
} // end function wordGenerator
int main(void)
{
    unsigned int loop; // loop counter
    unsigned int phoneNumber[7] = { 0 }; // holds phone number
    // prompt user to enter phone number
    printf("%s", "Enter a phone number one digit at a time");
    puts(" using the digits 2 thru 9:");
    // loop 7 times to get number
    for (loop = 0; loop <= 6; ++loop) {
        printf("%s", "? ");
        scanf_s("%d", &phoneNumber[loop]);
        // test if number is between 0 and 9
        while (phoneNumber[loop] < 2 || phoneNumber[loop] > 9) {
            printf("%s", "\nInvalid number entered. Please enter again: ");
            scanf_s("%d", &phoneNumber[loop]);
        } // end while
    } // end for
    wordGenerator(phoneNumber); // form words from phone number
} // end main
```

I am trying to write a C program that, given a seven-digit number, writes to a file every possible seven-letter word corresponding to that number. However I keep getting an error saying 'fopen_s': too few arguments for call in line 17. Can anyone help me figure this out? I am using Visual studios.

Comment: Reading [the docs for `fopen_s()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-s-wfopen-s) would be the natural place to start.

Comment: Hey John I have and I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Not even combined with the rather specific error message?  This is the `fopen_s()` call at line 17: `fopen_s("phone.out", "w")`.  It provides two arguments.  How many do the docs specify should be provided?

Comment: It does not specify, the only thing it states is that it is too few arguments

Comment: "Too few arguments" *is* a specific problem.  Perhaps we have a language issue here.  Do you know what "arguments" are in this context?  Do you know how to look at the function documentation (which in an earlier comment I linked for your convenience) to determine how many arguments are required, of what types, and what is the significance of each?  If you don't already know this stuff then you ***need*** to learn it.  That is why I have not given you a direct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the arguments you're using I think you want `fopen` instead of `fopen_s`.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen

Comment: I had fopen before however it told me to use fopen_s because fopen was unsafe. Then when I do the fopen_s I get the other error.